# Unable to configure a distributed transaction involving ActiveMQ and embedded H2 with Atomikos

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-transactions, atomikos

I am trying to set up a distributed transaction over an embedded H2 DB and ActiveMQ using Atomikos as the underlying JTA implementation in a Spring MVC app.
I have followed or visited almost every page on the web/stackoverflow related to the error I am encountering but haven't been able to figure it out.

Here are the relevant parts of the configuration:

```
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager getJtaTransactionManager(TransactionManager usrTxMgr,
                                                             @Qualifier("AtomikosUserTransaction") UserTransaction usrTx) {
    return new JtaTransactionManager(usrTx, usrTxMgr);
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager getJtaTransactionManager(TransactionManager usrTxMgr,
                                                           @Qualifier("AtomikosUserTransaction") UserTransaction usrTx) {
    return new JtaTransactionManager(usrTx, usrTxMgr);
}

@Bean(name = "AtomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public TransactionManager getAtomikosTransactionManager() {
    return new UserTransactionManager();
}

@Bean(name = "AtomikosUserTransaction")
public UserTransaction getAtomikosUserTransaction() throws SystemException {
    UserTransactionImp usrTx = new UserTransactionImp();
    usrTx.setTransactionTimeout(30);
    return usrTx;
}

@Bean(name = "H2X")
public AtomikosDataSourceBean getXADataSource() {
    JdbcDataSource h2x = new JdbcDataSource();
    h2x.setURL("jdbc:h2:˜/test1" + ";" + "INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:sql/create-db.sql'");
    h2x.setUser("sa");
    h2x.setPassword("");

    AtomikosDataSourceBean atkDs = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    atkDs.setXaDataSource(h2x);
    atkDs.setUniqueResourceName("AtomikosXADataSource");
    return atkDs;
}


@Autowired
@Bean(name = "H2TemplateX")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateX(@Qualifier("H2X") AtomikosDataSourceBean atkDs) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(atkDs);
}

 @Bean(name = "ActiveMQXACF")
public ConnectionFactory getXAConnectionFactory(@Value("${brokerURL:tcp://localhost:61616}") String brokerURL) {
    ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactory = new org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosJMSConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    atomikosJMSConnectionFactoryBean.setUniqueResourceName("AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory");
    atomikosJMSConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMQXAConnectionFactory);

    return atomikosJMSConnectionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "JMSTemplateX")
public JmsTemplate getXAJMSTemplate(@Autowired @Qualifier("ActiveMQXACF") ConnectionFactory cf, @Value("${JMSDestination}") String destination) {
    JmsTemplate jt = new JmsTemplate();
    jt.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    jt.setDefaultDestinationName(destination);
    jt.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return jt;
}
```

These are the methods that are annotated @Transactional. They are all in different service/repository/component classes.

```
@Transactional
public void saveMessage(String message) {
    messageSaver.insertMessage(message);
    processor.processMessage(message);
}

@Transactional
public void processMessage(final String message){
    jmsTemplate.send("Queue1", new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage(message);
        }
    });
}

@Transactional
public void insertMessage(String msg) {
    if (msg.toLowerCase().contains("bad")) throw new RuntimeException("Can't  Commit to DB !!");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("msg", msg);
    String sql = "insert into TBL_MESSAGE (message) values(:msg)";
    jdbcTemplateX.update(sql, params);
}
```

Putting Spring Transactions in debug, I see that Spring registers the transactional methods and the Atomikos UserTransactionManager and UserTransactionImp classes correctly.
Shortened logs:

```
   Adding transactional method 'business.MessageDaoImpl.insertMessage
   Adding transactional method 'business.OrderProcessor.processMessag
   Adding transactional method 'business.MessageServiceService.saveMe
   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Using JTA    UserTransaction: com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp@24714a15
   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Using JTA TransactionManager: com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager@65199846
```

These are some logs from Atomikos debug log:

```
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'AtomikosXADataSource': getConnection()...
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'AtomikosXADataSource': init...
    WARN http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'AtomikosXADataSource': poolSize equals default - this may cause performance problems!
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'AtomikosXADataSource': initializing with [ xaDataSourceClassName=null, uniqueResourceName=AtomikosXADataSource, maxPoolSize=1, minPoolSize=1, borrowConnectionTimeout=30, maxIdleTime=60, reapTimeout=0, maintenanceInterval=60, testQuery=null, xaProperties=[], loginTimeout=0, maxLifetime=0]
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource - AtomikosXADataSource: refreshed XAResource
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for conn5: url=jdbc:h2:˜/test1 user=SA: calling prepareStatement(insert into TBL_MESSAGE (message) values(?))...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for conn5: url=jdbc:h2:˜/test1 user=SA: close()...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory': createConnection()...
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory': init...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory': getReference()...
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory': initializing with [ xaConnectionFactory=org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory@59883d41, xaConnectionFactoryClassName=null, uniqueResourceName=AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory, maxPoolSize=1, minPoolSize=1, borrowConnectionTimeout=30, maxIdleTime=60, reapTimeout=0, maintenanceInterval=60, xaProperties=[], localTransactionMode=false, maxLifetime=0, ignoreSessionTransactedFlag=true]
    INFO http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource - AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: refreshed XAResource
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for resource AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: creating XA-capable session...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy - atomikos xa session proxy for resource AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: calling toString on JMS driver session...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy - atomikos xa session proxy for resource AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: calling createQueue on JMS driver session...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy - atomikos xa session proxy for resource AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: calling createProducer on JMS driver session ActiveMQSession {id=ID:IG11061-58249-1492635876500-5:2:2,started=false}
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy - atomikos xa session proxy for resource AtomikosJMSConnectionFactory: calling createTextMessage on JMS driver session...
    DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsMessageProducerProxy - atomikos MessageProducer proxy for ActiveMQMessageProducer { value=ID:IG11061-58249-1492635876500-5:2:2:1 }: send ( message )...
    WARN http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.atomikos.jms.ConsumerProducerSupport - atomikos MessageProducer proxy for ActiveMQMessageProducer { value=ID:IG11061-58249-1492635876500-5:2:2:1 }: The JMS session you are using requires a JTA transaction context for the calling thread and none was found.
```

The error while sending the message says that the message send should be done in the context of a JTA transaction which I was assuming would be created at the first method call due to the presence of the @Transactional annotation.

I looked at the source of the Atomikos class producing the error but could not figure out much.The error happens in the enlist() method:

```
   protected void enlist() throws JMSException {
    CompositeTransaction ct = null;
    CompositeTransactionManager ctm = this.getCompositeTransactionManager();
    boolean enlist = false;
    if(ctm != null) {
        ct = ctm.getCompositeTransaction();
        if(ct != null && ct.getProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.jta.transaction") != null) {
            enlist = true;
        }
    }

    if(enlist) {
        this.registerSynchronization(ct);

        try {
            this.state.notifyBeforeUse(ct);
        } catch (InvalidSessionHandleStateException var6) {
            String msg1 = "error during enlist: " + var6.getMessage();
            LOGGER.logWarning(this + ": " + msg1);
            AtomikosJMSException.throwAtomikosJMSException(msg1, var6);
        }
    } else {
        String msg = "The JMS session you are using requires a JTA transaction context for the calling thread and none was found.\nPlease correct your code to do one of the following: \n1. start a JTA transaction if you want your JMS operations to be subject to JTA commit/rollback, or\n2. increase the maxPoolSize of the AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean to avoid transaction timeout while waiting for a connection, or\n3. create a non-transacted session and do session acknowledgment yourself, or\n4. set localTransactionMode to true so connection-level commit/rollback are enabled.";
        LOGGER.logWarning(this + ": " + msg);
        AtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException.throwAtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException(msg);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 3):

This link helped : 
http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/

Quoting:
"This means that you need to call your annotated method directly through an @Autowired bean or the transaction will never start. If you call a method on an @Autowired bean that isn’t annotated which itself calls a public method that is annotated YOUR ANNOTATION IS IGNORED. This is because Spring AOP is only checking annotations when it first enters the @Autowired code."

I put @EnableTransactionMangement on my WebConfig class too and it worked !
Earlier, @EnableTransactionManagement annotation was only available on one of my RootConfig classes, alongwith
 @Transactional on a @Service method and on two subsequent @Repository methods.

I should probably read more on how Spring Transaction Boundaries are set and how does the various @Enable* annotations work internally.

Still not very clear, but it works for now.

Hope it helps somebody else too.